# Assign values to numpy array from list indices

Tags: python, list, numpy, indices

I have a numpy array and a list, say:

```
np_array = np.random.randint(0,3,(2,3))
np_array
array([[1, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 2]])

indices_list:
[7,8,9]
```

and would like to have a numpy array which takes its values from the indices of the list (i.e., if np_array has value 2, set indices_list[2] as value on new array):

```
np_array_expected
array([[8, 8, 9],
       [9, 8, 9]])
```

I did this unsuccessful attempt:

```
np_array[indices_list]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_27887/728354097.py", line 1, in <module>
    np_array[indices_list]

IndexError: index 7 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2


indices_list[np_array]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_27887/265649000.py", line 1, in <module>
    indices_list[np_array]

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: The first fails because `np_array` is the set of indices; `indices_list` has the values.  The second fails because lists can only be indexed with single values, not arrays.  If `indices_list` is actually an array (or converted to one), the task is trivial.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Would you mind accepting my answer, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the list to a numpy array as well, then it's simple indexing:

```
np.array(indices_list)[np_array]
```

does what you want, I think. Or not?

Comment: You're welcome. Would you mind accepting my answer? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This is simply indexing: `b[a]`, given the second array is also numpy array.

Output:

```
array([[8, 8, 9],
       [9, 8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my iterative solution :

```
>>> arr = np.array([[1,1,2],[2,1,2]])
>>> indices_list = [7,8,9]
>>> for i in range(arr.shape[0]) :
...     for j in range(arr.shape[1]) :
...         arr[i][j] = indices_list[arr[i][j]]

>>> print(arr)
```

Output :

```
array([[8, 8, 9],
       [9, 8, 9]])
```